# When is GIT quotient of a projective variety smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

It might be very basic, but my google search could not find an answer for this, nor the search in previous related questions.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, and let $G$ be a reductive group acting on $X$. 
Let $L$ be an ample $G$-equivariant line bundle on $X$. Define the GIT quotient of $X$ by $$X//^{L} G = Proj(\oplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})^G).$$

I would like to have some criterion for a point on this quotient to be a smooth point. I think it should be true for points corresponding to closed orbits of $G$ with free action, but I am more interested in points "on the boundary", namely points that corresponds to several orbits that are glued by the qoutient map $X \to X//^L G$.

Is there any criterion for that?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is smooth at a point $x$ mapping to the point in the quotient?  If so, then Luna's Etale Slice Theorem implies that $X//^{L} G$ is smooth at the image point of $x$ if and only if for the normal (vector) space $N_x$ to the orbit $G\cdot x$ in $X$, for the stabilizer subgroup $G_x$ of $x$, the quotient of the linear representation $N_x//G_x$ is smooth at the image of the origin.  Even if $G_x$ is finite, that is extremely rare (Chevalley-Shephard-Todd).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes I assume that the variety is smooth. However, it is not affine, so I don't see how Luna slice applies here. And moreover, I consider a point which correspond to several orbits that are identified in the quotient, if this makes sense.

Comment: By definition, the geometric quotient $X//^L G$ is glued together from open affine subsets, each of which is a quotient $D_{L^d}(s)//G$ of a $G$-invariant distinguished open affine $D_{L^d}(s)$.  Here $d$ varies over all positive integers, and $s$ varies over all sections in $H^0(X,L^d)^G$.  For each point $y$ of $D_{L^d}(s)//G$, for *every* $x\in D_{L^d}(s)$ mapping to $y$, the image of $y$ in $D_{L^d}(s)//G$ is smooth if and only if $N_x//G_x$ is smooth.